# How to get Title Text color of Toolbar?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my current project, I'm trying to translate color of Toolbar and it's Title Text from current color to a new color. But I can't find a function in the Toolbar something like `toolbar.getTitleTextColor()` but there is a function to set color.

Here's my layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:id="@+id/bottombarAppbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/bottombarToolbar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_hide"
        app:title="Categories"
        app:titleTextColor="#fafafa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The statement below causes error because it's not defined.

```
bottombarToolbar.getTitleTextColor()
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want:

**JAVA**

```
public int getTitleTextColor(Toolbar toolbar) {
            if (toolbar != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child instanceof TextView) {
                        return ((TextView) child).getCurrentTextColor();
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
}
```

**KOTLIN**

```
fun getTitleTextColor(toolbar: Toolbar?): Int {
    if (toolbar != null) {
        for (i in 0 until toolbar!!.getChildCount()) {
            val child = toolbar!!.getChildAt(i)
            if (child is TextView) {
                return (child as TextView).currentTextColor
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```